# How to Add series in JQplot dynamically?

Tags: javascript, json, charts, jqplot

I have data coming from JSON which have multiple series and data for the series, How can I add series based on JSON data?

```
[{"seriesNo":1,"value":22,"date":"Thu Dec 06 16:48:24 IST 2012"}, 
 {"seriesNo":2,"value":149,"date":"Thu Dec 06 16:48:24 IST 2012"},
 {"seriesNo":3,"value":163,"date":"Thu Dec 06 16:48:24 IST 2012"},
 {"seriesNo":4,"value":87,"date":"Thu Dec 06 16:48:24 IST 2012"}, 
 {"seriesNo":5,"value":102,"date":"Thu Dec 06 16:48:24 IST 2012"}]
```

Comment: http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php ?

Comment: Its been given in examples,http://www.jqplot.com/tests/data-renderers.php

Comment: @ShamithaSilva link you have provided is only for data rendering, I am trying here to add series in live JQplot.

Comment: No, Just look at the code for "Ajax JSON Data Renderer" chart. here they have mentioned how you can provide the above (your json) string.